# Code for set the url as usernameq

Tags: php

I use a code to set the URL as:

http://domainname.com/user

The problem is that I use some masks in my .htaccess, so what we see in the URL is not always the real path of the file.

What I need is to get the URL, what is written in the URL, nothing more and nothing less—the full URL.

I need to get how it appears in the Navigation Bar in the web browser, and not the real path of the file on the server.

Comment: Supply the relevant code so that we can help you.

Comment: I am using user.domain.com but now want to use this as domain.com/user with php code, how to do this.

Comment: Please help what php code i need to use username after domain.com/username

Comment: When posting a question, please remember that we know nothing at all about your application. We do know PHP, but everything that you built and belongs to your application, you have to show and explain!

Comment: Nothing sir, let me explain, i am using username.domain.com but now i don't want use subdomain as user, i want users as  domainname.com/username, please give me any php code for same, mean how to get value after / slash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to simple check in PHP what's the value of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

or `substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],1)` if you want to remove leading slash

Comment: I want value after slash

Comment: @user3852194 Look at edited answer

Comment: Thanks Marcin to try help me, I am new in php so sorry to distrueb u again, as i explain above, I have a applicaction and have a config file where we set username.domain.com to start user account, but now i don't want use this process on subdomain, i want only domainname.com/usernane, i want to know how to get username calue via php code...

Comment: @user3852194 That's exactly what this code do. If you have your htaccess it simple will work and display you username

Comment: Thanks, and is there any posiblity to add username after domain name via php code...

Comment: You can simple create url `$url = 'http://yourdomain.com/'.$username;`

Comment: Hello Marcin, thanms for my help, i am able to get username but now problem is how to rewrite with htaccess as this username will change every time when so how to point this to main domain with htaccess, pls give a htaccess code to rewrite dynamic subdirectory  code to main domain.

Comment: @user3852194 You should ask new question in separate thread displaying in details what you have now and what you want